# Can't get extras from a PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

i always got nullPointer when i try to get back the ID of my notification...
here's the code of my intent definition:

```
public static void criaNotification(Context context, CharSequence tickerText, CharSequence title,
                                    CharSequence message, int id, Intent intent){

    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("Tipo", "notification");
    params.putInt("id", id);

    intent.putExtras(params);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and here is where i try to retrieve the extras but i always get nullPointer:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
final Bundle params = intent.getExtras();

if(params.getString("Tipo").equals("notification")){
    despertador = dbHelp.selectPorId(Integer.parseInt(params.getString("id")));
```

that's it... as you can see, i had already tried to use that flag in my PendingIntent

Comment: Where are you retrieving the extra from? Give more context on where your execute the second part of your code. Because it seems that `getIntent()` isn't the one you should use.

Comment: im retrieving in on activity...

Answer (score 1):

You use `params.putInt("id", id);` but `params.getString("id")`. Use either `int` or `String` but don't mix them.

Comment: sorry, i had already fixed this thing with putInt and String, but i'm always getting the nullPointer, i don't know what's happening... i tried putInt, getInt and i always got 1, with String - String it's always a nullPointer...